# location dash bootstrap navbar

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I have a navbar where i want the links in the center. I have them now on the right using classname 'ml-auto' but i cant' manage them to move to the center. Anyone who can help? Below my code.

```
nav_item = dbc.Nav(
    [
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("World Map", active= True, href="/page-1")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Table", active= True, href="/page-2")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Moran's l", active= True, href="/page-3")),
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("Scatter Plots", active= True, href="/page-4"))
    ],
    fill= True
)

navbar = dbc.Navbar(
    [
        html.A(
            # Use row and col to control vertical alignment of logo / brand
            dbc.Row(
                [
                    dbc.Col(html.Img(src= oord_logo, height="100px"), className="ml-5"),
                ],
                align="center",
                no_gutters=True,
            ),
            href="https://plot.ly",
        ),
        dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler"),
        dbc.Nav([nav_item], navbar=True, className="ml-auto",)
    ],
    color="white",
    dark=False,
    className = "mb-5"
)
```

Comment: have you tried using `className="m-auto"` instead of `className="ml-auto"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mr-auto` instead of `ml-auto`.

With `mr-auto` you get margin on the right. This is what you want since you want the element with this class (the `Nav` component) displayed on the left.

---

Unrelated to the problem, but you nest one `Nav` component in another which seems unnecessary. Also you've put the `NavbarToggler` component in the middle which means the hamburger button generated by this component will also be displayed in the middle.